# Как правильно написать такой mysql запрос?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос вида

```
SELECT *, (YEAR(current_date())-YEAR(date_of_birth)) as age FROM `tbl_user` WHERE (role!="admin") GROUP BY age
```

Работает как надо. Вычисляет количество лет пользователей и группирует их по количеству лет. Но если я захочу посмотреть всех пользователей старше, например, 25-ти лет, то получу ошибку с описанием, что такого поля, как age, не существует. Пример:

```
SELECT *, (YEAR(current_date())-YEAR(date_of_birth)) as age FROM `tbl_user` WHERE (role!="admin") AND age>'25'
```

Подскажите, что не так, почему и как сделать, чтобы заработало? И да. Можно использовать только Mysql (никаких php и т.д.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно часть условия из `WHERE` перенести в `HAVING`. Данные, полученные через агрегацию таблицы, невозможно отфильтровать в момент выборки.

Пример:

```
SELECT *, (YEAR(current_date())-YEAR(date_of_birth)) as age FROM tbl_user WHERE (role!="admin") HAVING age > 25
```

`WHERE` отработает в тот момент, когда будет строиться список "не админов". В то же время будет подсчитываться возраст.
`HAVING` отфильтрует уже по подсчитанным данным.

Comment: В этом запросе и нет агрегации. Там проблема с тем, что вычисляемое значение - это не колонка, а значит, по ней сортировать нельзя.

И вообще у вас в примере одновременно живут HAVING и WHERE.

Comment: @Etki, не совсем понимаю, почему в одном запросе не может быть where и having. Плюс ко всему именно по вычисляемому значению и можно сортировать, но нельзя закидывать его в where. И тут на помощь как раз приходит having. Так что пример, предложенный @dimka3210, полностью решает поставленную задачу. Если я в чем не прав - прошу поправить.

Comment: @makbeth, потому что HAVING - это и есть WHERE, только для агрегативных запросов. Они взаимоисключающи.

Comment: @Etki, да вы правы. Для корректного запроса надо убрать из условия where, и тогда он окажется полностью правильным.

Comment: @Etki, на Mysql 5.5 выполняется без проблем WHERE с HAVING вместе. Даже Warning нету. Честно сказать я про HAVING толком не знаю. Только давно читал описание. Но не вижу проблемы, почему оно не должно работать. Можешь кинуть линк, почему их нельзя вместе использовать?

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле говорит, что можно
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177458.aspx

Comment: @dimka3210, оно и работает вместе. Просто, видимо, так не принято писать. Как бы дублирование кода, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Хз, был уверен до этого момента, что нельзя. Что касательно MSDN - это справка по продуктам microsoft, точно можно узнать по запросу ANSI SQL-92.

Comment: @Etki, разница между `HAVING` и `WHERE` следующая: `WHERE` выкидывает записи до получения результирующего набора, а `HAVING` выкидывает их уже после получения этого набора.

Сравните план выполнения (PK на ID):

    explain SELECT * FROM city WHERE ID = 10;
    explain SELECT * FROM city HAVING ID = 10;

Первый запрос вернет сразу одну запись по PK, а второй сначала сформирует набор из всех записей, а потом уже среди них выберет ту, у которой ID равен 10.

Поэтому все, что можно - в `WHERE` (чтобы оптимизатор работал), а что нельзя тогда уж в `HAVING`

UPD: stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292